# Problems with auto update of page

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, live-refresh

The page auto update is nice, but could it be reworked?

- If new answers have been posted and I click on the grey refresh box ("New answers have been posted..."), the answers counter does not change;
- sometimes, if it is the first answer, the ordering tabs do not appear;
- new answers are put on top, but this does not combine well with the default question ordering (oldest). I would change it to "active" in this case.

Answer (score 4):

> If new answers have been posted and I click on the grey refresh box
>   ("New answers have been posted..."), the answers counter does not
>   change;

This appears to be a regression - I have pushed a bit more robust fix so it should be fixed after the next build.

> sometimes, if it is the first answer, the ordering tabs do not appear;

Tabs will be visible even when a question has no answers after clicking on the "new answers" bar.

> new answers are put on top, but this does not combine well with the
>   default question ordering (oldest). I would change it to "active" in
>   this case.

I will look at solutions for this - the current implementation will just load the answer right under the new answer bar.

As always, wait for the next build.

Comment: Nice, Geoff, this seems to work now perfectly.